# Getting Many Errors when starting Spark-Shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I downloaded spark using "brew install apache-spark". When I start spark-shell, I get tons of errors. When I try creating a spark session:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Spark Postgresql Example").getOrCreate()
```

I get the following errors:

```
Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true, username = APP. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'metastore_db' with class loader org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1@73a116d, see the next exception for details.

Caused by: ERROR XJ040: Failed to start database 'metastore_db' with class loader org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1@73a116d, see the next exception for details.

org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusDataStoreException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true, username = APP. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'metastore_db' with class loader org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1@73a116d, see the next exception for details.

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true, username = APP. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'metastore_db' with class loader org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1@73a116d, see the next exception for details.

Nested Throwables StackTrace:
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true, username = APP. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'metastore_db' with class loader org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1@73a116d, see the next exception for details.

17/07/18 13:12:35 WARN HiveMetaStore: Retrying creating default database after error: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true, username = APP. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'metastore_db' with class loader org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1@73a116d, see the next exception for details.

javax.jdo.JDOFatalDataStoreException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true, username = APP. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'metastore_db' with class loader org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1@73a116d, see the next exception for details.

17/07/18 13:12:35 ERROR Schema: Failed initialising database.
Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true, username = APP. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'metastore_db' with class loader org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1@73a116d, see the next exception for details.
```

and much more..

```
 scala> import spark.implicits._
 <console>:18: error: not found: value spark
   import spark.implicits._
          ^
```

Comment: Spark-shell gives you a SparkSession object on startup, why do you make a new one?

Comment: I tried but it says variable spark not found

Comment: I think your installation got messed up somehow, but assuming you get the actual startup prompt, it will say `Spark context available as 'sc'` and `Spark session available as 'spark'`

Comment: Your error is saying it cannot open the embedded derby database, which is trying to be created in the folder you run the command... so does your current user have permission to do that in the folder you are in? Also, `username = APP` looks odd

Answer (score 2):

This error appears to happen when spark-shell does not exit gracefully, and then a new session invokes spark-shell.try restarting the spark-shell

If it is still happening you can try this to create session

```
var sparkSession = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSessionbuilder.getOrCreate
var sparkContext = sparkSession.sparkContext
```

you can try removing metastore_db/dbex.lck this will fix your problem

you can also configure  the hive-site.xml in {SPARK_HOME}/conf, the context automatically creates a metastore called  metastore_db and a folder called warehouse in the current directory.fixing the permission issues in the directory from which you are launching spark-shell can solve your problem

Comment: Removing metastore_db/dbex.lck fixed this for me