# Cannot get a hello world running in Apache Spark on Ubuntu

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I am trying to setup Apache Spark on Ubuntu and output hello world.

I added these two lines to .bashrc

```
export SPARK_HOME=/home/james/spark
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin
```

(Where spark is a symbolic link to the current spark version I have).
I run

```
spark-shell
```

From the command line and the shell starts up with hundreds of errors, for example:

```
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalDataStoreException: Unable to open a test 
connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true, username = APP. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app)
Caused by: ERROR XJ041: Failed to create database 'metastore_db', see the next exception for details.
Caused by: ERROR XBM0A: The database directory '/home/james/metastore_db' exists. However, it does not contain the expected 'service.properties' file. Perhaps Derby was brought down in the middle of creating this database. You may want to delete this directory and try creating the database again.
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true, username = APP.
Caused by: org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException: Failed to create database 'metastore_db', see the next exception for details.
```

My Java version:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

I try to open a simple text file with scala:

```
scala> val textFile = sc.TextFile("test/README.md")
<console>:17: error: not found: value sc
```

I read I need to create a new SparkContext. So I try this:

```
scala> sc = SparkContext(appName = "foo")
<console>:19: error: not found: value sc
val $ires1 = sc
             ^
<console>:17: error: not found: value sc
       sc = SparkContext(appName = "foo")
```

And this:

```
scala> val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
<console>:17: error: not found: type SparkContext
       val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
                    ^
<console>:17: error: not found: value conf
       val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

I have no idea what is going on. All I need is the correct set up then there should be no problems.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: see [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45176512/getting-many-errors-when-starting-spark-shell)

Comment: Thank you. I managed to reinstall and used an older version and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete `metastore_db` folder and `derby.log` file. I had the same problem and deleting those things fixed it. I'd assume there was some corrupted files in db folder due to Spark not closing properly.